# Laravel how i get route with name in blade

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a route same like this.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
    'as'=>'front.',
    'middleware'=>['localeSessionRedirect','localizationRedirect',]],function ()
{
    Route::get('/view/post/{id}', [ExtraController::class, 'SinglePost'])->name('post_view');
});
```

So i want call this route in blade.How i get post_view route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this in your view:

```
//example:
<a href="{{route('post_view', $post->id)}}">
```

Comment: It get me Route [post_view] not defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{{route('post_view', [$post->id])}}">
```